# javascript: onblur value not reappearing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get 'Name' to reappear in this input box if the user take the focus away from the box without typing anything.

This is the code that is not working:

```
<input type="text" value="Name" onfocus="if(this.value='Name'){this.value=''}"  onblur="if(this.value=''){this.value='Name'}"/>
```

Hoping someone can help me out quickly with it!

Comment: `if(this.value='')` is assigning , you need to check `if(this.value==='')`

Comment: An aside as the issue has been resolved by other posters - If you don't mind lack of IE support before v10 why not use the placeholder attribute within the Input tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by [Rob Sedgwick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394663/rob-sedgwick), use `===` for comparing instead of `=`,

```
<input type="text" value="Name" onfocus="if(this.value==='Name'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value===''){this.value='Name'}" />
```

P.S. You can use placeholder for this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
```